# Console Logs not showing in Google Cloud Platform after program initializes

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, console.log

Relatively new to deploying on Google Cloud. I recently created an Node / Typescript application that is completely backend, in the sense that there are no routes or anything hit or anything for a user to see in a browser. It just runs in the background and performs functions on certain days of the month.

When I deployed my app on the cloud, everything was met with success. All files were uploaded and all services updated. But when I check on the Google Cloud Logs Explorer, there are no logs pertaining to what I should be seeing.

Here is the code that runs on start up inside my index.js file:

```
function init() {
    console.log("App starting...");
    cycle();
}
init();
```

I am aware that when the code is deployed on GCA, it uses a start script from your package.json. Mine is set to:

```
"start": "node dist/index.js"
```

So after I compile the TS code, this directory and file are created. But still, when the code is up and running with no issues, no console logs will show in the logger. Is base console logging not compatible with the log interface on the Gcloud platform?

My app.yaml file is present and contains nodejs16 as the runtime btw.

Comment: Yes, logs written to stdout and stderr should be captured by Cloud Logging. It would be helpful if you could include in your question (a) what test you have to determine that your app is running correctly; (b) what you're doing to read the logs. I assume (!?) that you're using the App Engine Cron service to schedule the jobs?